# Issue with distance point-to-line

Tags: geometry

I am having a small issue with the distance calculation of a point-to-line and I cannot find the mistake.

I have the line:

$$x + 2y + 3 = 0$$

And I am trying to compute its distance to point $(x_0, y_0) = (0,0)$. According to the well-known formula:

$$ d = \frac{\left|ax_0+by_0+c\right|}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} = \frac{\left|3\right|}{\sqrt{5}} = 1.3416$$

Now, I try to compute the same distance on a different manner. The line intersects the $y$ axes at $p=(0, -1.5)$. I am trying to solve the following triangle (sorry for the cheap plotting):

[image: Triangle to solve]

The distance computed before should correspond to the length of the red segment (perpendicular to the line that goes through the desired point), which could also be computed as:
$$ d = 1.5 \cdot cos(30^{\circ}) = 1.299$$

Both results for the length of the red segment do not match. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angles are wrong - instead of $30^0$ it should be $\arctan(0.5) = 26.56^0$

Comment: Ah, that's it! I knew it was a small mistake somewhere I forgot to check. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the process step by step instead of using a calculator/grapher, and (ultimately) verify Dhanvi's claim.

So, to find the distance from the line (call it $\ell$) to $(0,0)$, we will want the line perpendicular to $\ell$ through the origin (call this one $p$).

The equation of $p$ will have negative reciprocal slope to $\ell$ and $y$-intercept $0$. Then we have that

$$y_p (x) = 2 x$$

Meanwhile, $\ell$ has the equation

$$y_\ell(x) = -\frac 1 2 x - \frac 3 2$$

So your triangle has two points already: $(0,0)$ and $(0,-3/2)$. The third is where $\ell$ and $p$ intersect. Set the two equations equal and solve for $x$:

$$2x = - \frac 1 2 x - \frac 3 2 \implies x = - \frac 3 5$$

Substitution can get us that, then, the corresponding $y$ is at $y = -6/5$.

We can then find the distances between these points, and we get that

\begin{align*}
\Big( \text{distance from } (0,0) \text{ to } (0,-1.5) \Big) &= 1.5 \\
\Big( \text{distance from } (-3/5,-6/5) \text{ to } (0,-1.5) \Big) &= \frac{3}{2 \sqrt 5} \\
\Big( \text{distance from } (-3/5,-6/5) \text{ to } (0,0) \Big) &= \frac{3}{\sqrt 5}
\end{align*}

Obviously, one angle is formed by the first and last sides. It has angle $\theta$, and it will be given by

$$\theta = \arccos \left( \frac{3 / \sqrt 5}{1.5} \right) \approx \boxed{26.57^\circ}$$

This is where your problem lies. That top angle of your triangle is not $30^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

THe equation of  line:

$y=-\frac 12 x-\frac32$

Equation of red line:

$y=2x$

So the coordinates of intersection is : $(x=-\frac 35, y=\frac 65)$

The distance is:

$d=\sqrt {(-\frac 35)^2+(\frac{6}5)^2}=1.3416$

Comment: Thank you. I think you mixed up the signs a bit of the x for both lines, right?

Comment: @Javi, Yes. corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The polar form of the straight line is

$$ x\cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha = p =1.3496$$

where $\alpha = \cos^{-1}\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt 5}$ is counter-clockwise rotation of the red normal reckoned from x-axis lying in the third quadrant.